# 0dp view does not resize correctly when another view in layout changes size afterwards

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bg"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Press button to start"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<MySurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Start process" 
    android:textSize="35sp"/>

<MyAdView
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ap:animation="fade"
    ap:banner_type="inappad"
    ap:placementType="interstitial"
    ap:test_mode="false"
    ap:canShowMR="false"></MyAdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The view "myAdView" is an Advert banner that resizes when its content is received from the server. When this happens the banner height resizes but the surface view with id "@+id/surfaceView" that is dynamically resized (0dp in height) does not resize to follow the new layout view sizes. How could I solve this problems? I have tried several solutions but no one worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you provide little more details?

Comment: I don't have any code handling the layout at this moment. Don't know if this is what you are asking for. Everything is generated from the layout xml file I have posted. The main problem is that initially the height of the banner is 0 because it has not been retrieved yet from the server and when it is received it grows height to accommodate it, but the view with 0dp does not shrinks to adjust its size because now there are less free space.